# An alternative Swift method to PHP `pack()` method

Tags: php, ios, swift, pack

I am looking for an alternative Swift method to PHP `pack()` method

to return the same value for this code line

```
echo pack('H*', sprintf("%02X",1));
```

Based on `w3schools` website:

```
echo base64_encode(pack('H*', sprintf("%02X",1)));
```

prints `AQ==` and

```
echo base64_encode(sprintf("%02X",1));
```

prints `MDE=`

Comment: And what value is that?

Comment: I tried it in `w3schools` website and it's printed `01` for this code `echo sprintf("%02X",1);` and got empty value for this code `echo pack('H*', sprintf("%02X",1));` @JoakimDanielson

Comment: So you want an empty value or are you saying you don’t know what that php code will output?

Comment: I don't know what should be the returned value and I want some way to get the same value in `Swift`.

Comment: Based on `w3schools` 

`echo base64_encode(pack('H*', sprintf("%02X",1)));` returns `AQ==`
`echo base64_encode(sprintf("%02X",1)); ` returns `MDE=`
@JoakimDanielson